# File and links not accessible after generating a .war file with spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a spring boot application that runs very well, But after generating a war file so as I can run the application on separate tomcat server not the embedded one, I am unable to access some pages and files.  I have rename the generated war file to **mywarfile.war** .This qusetion has two separate relate issues.

**First issue**-Access a linked page

Below is the link inside **index.html** that will lead to a method that will perform some code then leads to **all.html**

```
   <button class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="/all"> View Welding Product Record </a></button>
```

Method

```
  @GetMapping("/all")
  public String getAllProducts(Model model){ 
          //.....codes
          return "all"
       }
```

Everything works fine with embedded tomcat with spring boot, but when click the link with the war file deployed to separated tomcat server it redirects to http://localhost:8080/all and shows below error.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/all] is not available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.65

The mywarfile.war is placed on **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\mywarfile.war**

But if I type manual on url http://localhost:8080/mywarfile/all I can access the page. What could be the cause of this. And How can I fix it.

**Second issue** - Access images

I have a background image in my index.html that can be accessed before generating the war file, But after generating the war file and run it on separate tomcat server I cannot see the image.

Below is the code in index.html

```
     <style>
     body{background-image: url('/images/ocean.jpg');}
     <style>
```

This is the structure of how I store the images in my project

```
     \src\main\resources\static\images\ocean.jpg
```

what could be the cause of this and how can I solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML files clearly assume that the project is deployed at the root of the server. Call the WAR file `ROOT.war` to deploy it at the root of the Tomcat server.

Comment: How it has work Thank you so much.